# Speed up reading results in batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, netsh

What I am trying to do, is speed up  my reading results of batch file.

Am trying to get different values using netsh commands and then present them in my script console but it takes to long.
See below a small part of my script to get the idea. (this is just a small part, I'm actually getting around 50 different values and using more netsh commands)

Does anybody know a way to speed up the process?

```
.
.
.
netsh interface ipv4 show config %AdapterLAN%  >temp
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('findstr "IP Address" temp') do set ip=%%i
echo.  IP Address        : %ip%

for /f "tokens=5 delims=) " %%i in ('findstr  "Subnet Prefix" temp') do  set mask=%%i
echo.  Mask              : %mask%

for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('findstr  "Gateway:" temp')  do set gateway=%%i
echo.  Gateway           : %gateway%

for /f "tokens=1,5,6" %%a in ('findstr  "DNS" temp') do set dns1=%%a&set dns5=%%b&set dns6=%%c
If "%dns1%"=="Statically" set dns=%dns5%
if "%dns1%"=="DNS"        set dns=%dns6% 
echo.  DNS Server        : %dns%

for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('findstr "Gateway Metric" temp') do set GMetric=%%i
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in           ('findstr "InterfaceMetric" temp')   do set IMetric=%%i
set /a metricLAN=Gmetric + imetric 
echo.  Metric            : %metricLAN%

for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('find "DHCP enabled" temp') do set LANDHCP=%%i
If "%dns1%"=="Statically"  set xx=Static
if "%dns1%"=="DNS"         set xx=DHCP  
If /i %LANDHCP%==No        set LANDHCP=Static
if /i %LANDHCP%==YES       set LANDHCP=DHCP
echo.  Obtained IP       : %LANDHCP%
echo.  Obtained DNS      : %xx%
for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('getmac /v /fo csv ^| find """%AdapterLAN-without-Q%""" ')  do set macLAN=%%a
echo.  MAC-Addres        : %macLAN%
del temp
.
.
.
netsh wlan show profile >temp
.
Do a similar process of getting values from another netsh command sent them
in the temp file …echo the one I want on the screen ..delete the file etc.
```

Comment: Try executing every `netsh` block in parallel using `start /b "%~0" actionXX`, add `if not "%1"=="" goto %1` at the start of bat file, add `:action1` etc. labels for the blocks. To signal completion of each section you can create a temporary file, it's fast comparing to `netsh`.

Answer (score 0):

Next approach could be a bit faster (no temporary file(s), **updated** no multiple `findstr`):

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "AdapterLAN=wiredEthernet"
set "IMetric="
set "GMetric="
for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%G in ('
  netsh interface ipv4 show config "%AdapterLAN%"^|findstr /N /R "^"
') do (
    rem echo G="%%G" H="%%H" I="%%I"
    if "%%I"=="" (
      rem line  1   skip
      rem line  2 = Configuration for interface
      rem line 10 = DNS server #2 etc.
    ) else (
        set "hh=%%H"
        set "xx=!hh:IP Address=!"
        if not "!hh!"=="!xx!" for /F "tokens=1*" %%i in ("%%I") do set "ip=%%i"

        set "xx=!hh:Subnet Prefix=!"
        if not "!hh!"=="!xx!" for /F "tokens=3 delims=) " %%i in ("%%I") do set "mask=%%i"

        set "xx=!hh:Default Gateway=!"
        if not "!hh!"=="!xx!" for /F "tokens=1*" %%i in ("%%I") do set "gateway=%%i"

        set "xx=!hh:Gateway Metric=!"
        if not "!hh!"=="!xx!" for /F "tokens=1*" %%i in ("%%I") do set "GMetric=%%i"

        set "xx=!hh:InterfaceMetric=!"
        if not "!hh!"=="!xx!" for /F "tokens=1*" %%i in ("%%I") do set "IMetric=%%i"

    )
)
echo(  IP Address        : [%ip%]
echo(  Mask              : [%mask%]
echo(  Gateway           : [%gateway%]
set /a metricLAN=Gmetric + IMetric 
echo(  Metric            : [%metricLAN%]
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

**Output**:

```
==>D:\bat\SO\31356115.bat
  IP Address        : [192.168.1.100]
  Mask              : [255.255.255.0]
  Gateway           : [192.168.1.1]
  Metric            : [20]

==>
```

**Edit**

Here is another approach: unlike `netsh`, parsing the `wmic` command output seems to be a bit easier when used `get` verb together with `/value` switch as it's well defined and well structured. You could find here all the info as from `netsh`: next code snippet should read and make public a huge range of information about *all enabled NIC adapter(s)* in a defined local or remote computer:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "NetCount=0"
set "compName=%computername%" :: local or remote computer name
set "compIDXs="
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%N in ('
  wmic /node:"%compName%" NIC where "NetEnabled=TRUE" get InterfaceIndex /value 2^>NUL ^| find "="
') do for /F "tokens=*" %%n in ("%%N") do (
  for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('
    wmic /node:"%compName%" NIC where "InterfaceIndex=%%n" get /value 2^>NUL ^| find "="
  ') do for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ("%%G") do set "_%%n%%g"
  for /F "tokens=*" %%I in ('
    wmic /node:"%compName%" NICCONFIG where "InterfaceIndex=%%n" get /value 2^>NUL ^| find "="
  ') do for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ("%%I") do set "_%%n_%%i"
  set /A "NetCount+=1"
  set "compIDXs=!compIDXs! "%%n""
)
set _
rem sample of it:
echo compName=%compName% NetCount=%NetCount% compIDXs=%compIDXs%
for %%x in (%compIDXs%) do (
  echo enabled InterfaceIndex=%%~x  NetConnectionID=!_%%~xNetConnectionID!
  for /F "tokens=1,2 delims={}," %%i in ("!_%%~x_IPAddress!") do echo ipv4=%%~i ipv6=%%~j  
)
```

Read Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266) to see why any `wmic` command output is parsed via a couple of nested `for` loops.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Josef. I have try both ways but they are actually much more slower than the one I am currently using right now.